# Can I rely on order of commands in redis:monitor output?

Tags: redis

I use [monitor](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) redis command for debugging some flakiness in our integration tests. Does order of commands in output of monitor equal to real order of commands processed by server?

I use redis 3.0.7 from official redis:3.0 docker image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. In terms of implementation, before executing any command, Redis sends it to all `MONITOR`ing clients, so the order of commands in the the monitor stream matches the order of commands' execution.